# Python outputs AttributeError from an argparse module

Tags: python, attributes, argparse, attributeerror

Python gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Google_Map.py", line 246, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\Google_Map.py", line 232, in main
    username = args.username
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'username'enter code here
```

I guess I must have passed the argument incorrectly. Please refer to the following code snippet below:

```
    def main():
# parse arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='InstaRaider')
parser.add_argument('-styledbyafrica', help='Instagram username')
parser.add_argument('-c:\python34\pikshor images\styledbyafrica', help='Where to save the images')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--num-to-download',
                    help='Number of posts to download', type=int)
parser.add_argument('-l', '--log-level', help="Log level", default='info')
args = parser.parse_args()
username = args.username
directory = op.expanduser(args.directory)

raider = InstaRaider(username, directory,
                     num_to_download=args.num_to_download,
                     log_level=args.log_level)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you check the [Argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) from Python Docs.

The reason it raises the `AttributeError` is because you're using different attribute names than the argument names you used in the argparser.

In the error you shared you're trying to get the `styledbyafrica` argument by using `username`. That clearly will not work. The directory will also give you problems there.